# How to get G+ response for G+ follow button

Tags: youtube, google-plus, facebook-like, pinterest, twitter-follow

I would like to add a feature to my website(created in WordPress - PHP) in which when once a user click on follow button, he will get 20 points for Facebook, Google +, Twitter, Pinterest, YouTube, Instagram.

[image: Attached is my design how I want.]

Comment: rewarding users in any way for following on facebook is not allowed. you should read the platform policy. also, your question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow, you need to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: After successful follow, I don't get any response how to get response after successful follow in twitter ?????

Answer (score 0):

For **Google+** Follow button : No callback as per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/)

For **Facebook**: Use [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.8)

Comment: I am using this only but event is getting fired but after following, I am getting no response.


twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        //on follow up code
    });

Comment: After successful follow, I don't get any response
how to get response after successful follow in twitter  ?????

Comment: @Aastha I am so sorry, this seems to be no more supported from 2015 end.. 
Try using twitteroauth as alternative..